# Install Docker-ce on Ubuntu 16.04 fails because of overlay

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04, overlay, ubuntu-server, docker-ce

Im running a vServer with `Ubuntu 16.04` installed. All packages seems up-to-date. My kernel-version is the following: `Linux 4.4.0-042stab130.1 x86_64`.
I want to install `docker-ce` for development purposes. Now everytime I try to install it via apt, it crashes because it cannot start docker.

`journalctl -u docker` shows me the following error messages:

```
level=error msg="'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support loaded.
level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support oom control
level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support memory swappiness
level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support kernel memory limit
level=warning msg="Unable to find cpu cgroup in mounts
level=warning msg="Unable to find cpuset cgroup in mounts
level=warning msg="mountpoint for pids not found
Error starting daemon: Devices cgroup isn't mounted
```

So I have no experience with the features provided by `overlay` or `overlay2`. I just barely read about it, and that it should be supported by the linux kernel as version 4 and above.

I do not know what to do, to make docker work.

Help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Got the same problem :(

Comment: I contacted my server provider about the problem, and the thing is, that they shipped out the images for ubuntu with a kernel that does not include overlayfs. So I recently changed my product that supports newer features such as KVM and docker. I reinstalled all of my products and migrated all of them to docker. It was hard work, but it was worth it.